# For FAB-1151 privacy solution, do you need to define the collection upfront before using XXXPrivateData API function?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Fabric v1.1 comes with a very interesting privacy feature (experimental for now) where data can be stored in private side-db within the scope of a collection which defines which organization have access to the private data.

If I am correct, we first need to define the collection before being able to use it. How do we do that?

Bonus question: is it possible to update the collection scope and include new organization after creation? (the same way we can include new organization to an already existing channel).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I am correct, we first need to define the collection before being
>   able to use it. How do we do that?

You define the collection when instantiating the chaincode... 
There is a new flag that you pass

```
--collections-config collections.json
```

and the json file looks like:

```
[
 {
     "name": "collectionMarbles",
     "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
     "requiredPeerCount": 1,
     "maxPeerCount": 2,
     "blockToLive":1000000
},
 {
     "name": "collectionMarblePrivateDetails",
     "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member')",
     "requiredPeerCount": 1,
     "maxPeerCount": 1,
     "blockToLive":3
 }
]
```

> Bonus question: is it possible to update the collection scope and
>   include new organization after creation? (the same way we can include
>   new organization to an already existing channel).

No, you can't update the collection in v1.1. 
It should be added in v1.2.

Comment: Thank you Yacovm, that answers my question. Is it possible to upgrade the chaincode and overwrite the chaincode policy as well as the related collection?

Comment: Also, I can't find any example online. Can anyone help?